# [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine]playeffect:@""] overloading probleam

Tags: iphone, audio, cocos2d-iphone, simpleaudioengine

In my game one audio is paying using

`[[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine]playeffect:@"audio.aac"];`
function .

When I touch one sprite I played another audio which 1 sec.

My problem is that my first "audio.aac" stops when I touch sprite continuously for 8 - 10 times, any solution for it.

Help will be appreciated.

Comment: i used AVAudioplayer to sort this problem ...

now it working fine ..

Answer (score 0):

You have to use .wav 44100 Hz 16 bit stereo of .caff formats to play multiply sound effects at once.

Comment: i didn't get you .. 
i have two different file to play
one is of 2min and other is 1sec. 
while i am playing 1sec. file first file is going to mute ..

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
[[SimpleAudioEngine]sharedEngine]playBackroundMusic:@"backgroundmusic.aac"];
```

to have the 2 minute clip loop while your `playEffect`
runs separately.

Comment: I don't understand what your goal is...so you have background music playing, and a two-minute AND a one-second clip.  Do you want the two-minute clip to mute while you are playing the one-second one?  Or do you want to overlap the two?

Comment: i have one background music playing continuously .
while going on one scene i played one two min audio .
when i touch one sprite 1sec sound will be played ..
so if i touch that sprite continuously 1sec audio plays right but after few time 2 min audio get stop. 
i think i clear my self now